# Перевернуть html страницу

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Не с помощью rotate на 180, а показать другую сторону страницы.

Может есть какой-нибудь плагин для этого?

Скрыть один div и открыть другой по событию это конечно не сложно. Вопрос как симулировать эффект переворачивания?

Comment: Если вам нужен flip эффект, тогда это через css perspective + transform.

Comment: http://www.turnjs.com - откройте книгу со Стивом Джобсом например и полистайте ее. Браться нужно за угол страницы. 
Или вот еще http://pageflip.hu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть библиотека для создания подобных эффектов: [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)